# trying to understand this math.pow loop ,dont understand why the exponent has to be reduced by 1

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, pow

help me understand this:

```
function myPow(base, exponent) {
    var count = 0
    var power = base
    while (exponent-1 > count) {
        power *= base

        count++

    }
    return sum;
}
```

why do we exponent-1? for example if the numbers are 2,3
then we would basically get 2*2 and not 2*2*2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by doing this:

```
var power = base;
```

You're already taking care of the first exponent.

If you do this instead:

```
var power = 1;
```

Then your while loop can be:

```
while (exponent > count){
    ...
}
```

**Note** Your function is returning sum, but that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you friend, i got it now =]